# Non-conditional IFs

Tags: subordinate-clauses, questions, conditionals

So I've heard some (I don't know what to call) non-conditional Ifs, and I've been trying to figure it out how they work. It's not like the first time I get troubles with conditional sentences, I always kept thinking about them time and time, but I couldn't find any answer for some of them, some like when you need to (let me clarify with an example) :

```
I came there to see if you're okay.
```

As you clearly know, there's no such a grammatical sentence out there at least as far as I know. To my knowledge there are 4 of them and the one I just took an example of, is way different from the four.

The main question of mine is to get to know if there's any other kind of if or if-like sentences (in everyday English) ?!

Comment: The *if* in your example applies to *you're ok* - they may be ok, or they may be *not* ok. That's still conditional.

Comment: according to the four conditional sentences, it should have been something like "I came there to see if you'd be okay" ? or what ? I can't get it. @Lawrence

Comment: Please add a link to the 4 conditionals and ping me again to take a look at them.

Comment: Those are clear, aren't they? They're zero, first, second and third conditionals. Which one do you think my example is closer to ? @Lawrence

Comment: If the **if** could me replaced with **whether... or not**, it could be considered as non-conditional, e.g. I went there to see whether you are okay or not. I am not sure if you understand me = I am not sure whether you understand me or not. But remember, grammar books all differ in what to call each conditional.

Comment: There we go, I guess that kinda sounds of it. Thanks @Rathony

Comment: @DevinHudson My pleasure. That's just rule of thumbs, and that's why I didn't post it as an answer. Good luck.

Comment: @DevinHudson I was referring to the condition inherent in the sentence, which isn't what you are asking about. Your question is [now answered](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/310405/non-conditional-ifs?noredirect=1#comment700738_310405) so I'm bowing out.

Comment: No, [English does not have four conditionals](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/66143/141).

Comment: The Q is based on misconception/ inadequate background effort.

Comment: @Rathony You are quite right. This is interrogative-*if*, not conditional-*if*!!!

Comment: I suspect a big part of the confusion has to do with the fact that "if", in this case, does not enable/disable a subsequent action (unlike, eg, "If you are ready then we can leave").  Rather, it produces what is known in mathematics as a "Boolean value" -- something that is TRUE or FALSE -- and that value can then be treated as a "thing".  So the "thing" your speaker came to *see* is the Boolean value for "you're OK".  This concept causes confusion for a lot of novice computer programmers as well.

Comment: @Hotlicks. This is the question word *if* not the conditional word.

Comment: @LawrenceThis is the question-word *if*, not the conditional word *if*. It can be paraphrased by *whether* here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you seem to be talking about here is the so called "biscuit conditional", from J.L. Austin's famous example ["There are biscuits on the sideboard if you want them"](http://ww2.valdosta.edu/~asantas/Texts/Austin.pdf)

There is an important difference between a BC and 'normal' conditional. If we look a 'normal' conditional such as *the barbecue will be cancelled if it rains*, the barbecue being cancelled becomes true only if the condition of "it rains" becomes true. This is what makes it conditional.

In a BC such as *there is beer in the fridge if you want some*, assuming that the speaker spoke truly there is beer in fridge if you want it, and there is still beer in the fridge if you don't want it. In other words, the beer in the fridge is always true. It is not linked to a condition, so  a BC is not conditional.

So why do BCs exist, if all they do make an assertion? Why not just say *there is beer in the fridge"? The usual answer is that it is a hedge against being irrelevant or inappropriate, effectively: "I don't know if you want beer of not, but if you do it is in the fridge".

[There are some arguments against this explanation](https://www.illc.uva.nl/Research/Publications/Reports/PP-2007-35.text.pdf) though, so it is not cut and dried yet.

Comment: Nice links. Conditionals are my favourite topic! (But Devin's sentence is just an example of a subordinate interrogative clause functioning as the Complement of *see* - where *if* is an interrogative word, not a conditional one).

Comment: A true programmer puts two glasses on his night stand - a full one in case he wants to drink when he wakes up and an empty one in case he doesn't.

Comment: I consider the BC a thing of logic alone and nothing about grammar at all. See also: BlessedGeek on this page.

Answer (score 3):

There are two types of *if* in English. The first is *if* one found in conditional sentences. This is not the same *if* as we find in the Original Poster's sentence.

There is a second, very important *if*, which has nothing to do with conditionals at all. It is an interrogative word, a question word, which we use in subordinate interrogative clauses. We use it to introduce embedded yes/no questions. There is a second, similar word to *if*, the word *whether*. The Original Poster's example is not a biscuit conditional or a relevance conditional - it is not a conditional at all. It is a sentence with an embedded question inside it. We could use the word *whether* instead in this example:

- I came here to see whether you are OK.

This sentence means

- I came here to see: Are you OK?

So, in short, in English we have a conditional *if* and an interrogative *if*. The Original Poster's sentence uses an interrogative-*if* (question-*if*).

*Hope that's helpful!*

Comment: Please see my comment at RoaringFish

Comment: @Kris Hmm, what does that have to do with embedded questions?

Comment: There are two types of 'if' according to Austin, and that is what is usually taught to students, but there are other points of view. Here, for example, they propose three types of 'if' covering nine functions. (http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/E85-1032.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

All "if" predicates are conditional. Calling one of them *non-conditional-if* is rather oxymoronic.

The question has its answer in information science, particularly logic in linguistics.

The difference between the two is the placement of the conditional-test in the sequence of events.

1. -

   ```
   if (event A) 
   then {action B}
   else {action C}
   ```
2. -

   ```
   function isEvent(B)
   {
     action A { discover the event }
     if (event is B)
       return true
     else
       return false
   }
   ```

In 2nd case, an action is executed to find out what event happened, and if the event that happened is as expected, and to report the truth of the expectation to the decision maker.

The decision maker had deployed the function isEvent(expectedEvent) to report the conditional truth of the matter.

Comment: It's now even worse, I'm not here to make it more complicated that's what you did. Could you just make it simpler by some examples ? -I'm kinda poor at programming, you know-

Comment: This is not "programming". This human decision logic, panned out into its detailed micro-decisions.

Comment: No, not all "if" statements are conditional. If you say "there is beer in the fridge if you want it", there is beer in the fridge. It is not conditional on anything. Assuming, if course, that the utterer wasn't lying.