# If you haven't already watched my first video, there's a link to it in the description below. Ungrammatical?

Tags: conditionals

I just finished recording an audio file for one of my podcasts.  And I'm debating whether I should delete the following sentence:

> If you haven't already watched my first video, there's a link to it in the description below.

I am trying to suggest to viewers that they watch my videos in order, which I think the sentence does.  But I think this sentence is also ungrammatical and nonsensical.

Whether or not my viewers have watched my first video, a link to that video will be in the description.

I suppose I could change it to

> If you haven't already watched my first video, please watch that first. You can find a link to it in the description below.

But changing audio files is such a pain.  Would it be ok to leave the sentence as is?

Comment: Related: [Non-conditional IFs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/310405)

Comment: This conditional refers not to the content of the clause, but to its performative. It means 'If you haven't already watched my first video, I hereby tell you that there's a link to it in the description below.' That's because one can always add "I hereby tell you that `S`', to any sentence `S` without changing the meaning -- it's obvious, and therefore it is presupposed and can be referred to. Examples abound: _In case you weren't tuned in, the score is Detroit 2, Chicago 1; If you need one, there are umbrellas in the hall_. Etc.

Comment: For me, the gap is in the logic, not the grammar, worth resolving as follows: If you haven't already watched my first video yet, **use** the link to it in the description below.

Comment: Also related: [Term for if-then statements where the “then” part does not logically follow](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/379966/191178)